# Converting multiple geometry KML to Shapefile

Tags: shapefile, convert, geometry, kml, osgeo4w

I have a KML file with multiple geometry, points and polygons. I want to convert it to a point Shapefile and a polygon Shapefile.

Using OSGeo4W Shell I tried this :

```
ogr2ogr -where "OGR_GEOMETRY='Point'" -f "ESRI Shapefile" D:\env\transit_points.shp D:\env\mosquee.kml
ogr2ogr -where "OGR_GEOMETRY='Polygon'" -f "ESRI Shapefile" D:\env\transit_polygon.shp D:\env\mosquee.kml
```

I get two empty LINE shapefiles with empty tables with nothing but the row names.

Comment: Don't know is this works but worth a shot : https://mygeodata.cloud/converter/kml-to-shp

Comment: Already tried it,not working.

Comment: Try QGIS. Add KML to the canvas. Export as a feature -> shape file. Then for Geometry select the points, and then do steps over and select polygons.